# What's the easier way to overwrite CloudBlockBlob in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

What's the easier way to overwrite CloudBlockBlob in Azure?

Following code will work but is there an easier/cleaner way?

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();
blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
```

Comment: In the code above, where are you overwriting the blob? You're simply deleting the blob.

Comment: wouldn't getting a new reference after deleting will allow me to start a new one with same name?

Comment: Not really. Essentially both of your statements before and after `blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();` are identical. If you have fetched blob's properties then I would have agreed with you because then blockBlob would have the properties filled in. However in your scenario, you can easily get rid of last line in your code.

Comment: got it...looks like it keeps the reference even after deleting, and then I can upload new blocks.

Comment: Got it.. looks like it keeps the reference even after the Delete, and then I can upload new blocks. Thanks!